# SSRS Power shell command syntax for credential?

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

Does anyone know what is the syntax to insert a service account credential (to replace the useDefaultCredential) in this PS command line:

$ssrsProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $webServiceUrl'/ReportService2005.asmx?WSDL' -UseDefaultCredential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use the `-Credential` parameter and then use something like below as the variable being passed to it.

```
$(get-credential -UserName "Domain\Svc-User" -Message "Please enter password for Domain\Svc-User Account")
```

Or there is a way to convert a password to a secure string shown on the help page here where you simply have the user name and password saved in plain text variables which is less secure.

[Get-Credential](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/9cf2bb69-3cb4-4e97-8211-f91f81367ca3(v=wps.630).aspx)